# Prove that if $a \space | \space b$, then $a \space | \space 3b^3 - b^2 + 5b$.

Tags: proof-verification

I'm asked to prove that if $a \space | \space b$, then $a \space | \space 3b^3 - b^2 + 5b$. That is, if $a$ divides $b$, it also divides $3b^3 - b^2 + 5b$. My text does not have a solution to this problem, as it's even-numbered, so I was looking to see if someone could please verify that my proof (direct) is correct:

1. Assume that $a \space | \space b$. Then by definition, $b = ax$ for some integer $x$.
2. $3b^3 = 3a^3x^3$
3. $-b^2 = -a^2x^2$
4. $5b = 5ax$
5. Putting it all together, $3b^3 - b^2 + 5b = 3a^3b^3-a^2x^2+5ax$
6. Factoring the right side, $3b^3 - b^2 + 5b = a(3a^2x^3-ax^2+5x)$
7. Because $a$ and $x$ are both integers, the factor by which $a$ is multiplied on the right side is also an integer.
8. By definition, then $a \space | \space 3b^3 -b^2 + 5b$.

Please let me know if this is a valid proof or if there are any flaws in my logic.

Comment: It looks like you've made a typo in 2 and 5, $3a^3 b^3$ should be $3a^3 x^3$

Comment: Ah, right. My apologies. Edited.

Comment: Looks perfect otherwise though!

Comment: All right, thanks for verifying!

Comment: Why not just say that $3b^3-b^2+5b = b(3b^2-b+5)$ and so since $a$ divides one of the terms of the product, it must divide the whole product?

Comment: Any restrictions on $a$ and $b$ (other than the fact that they are integers)?

Comment: @gt6989b Thank you! Nope, Freeman, the only restriction was that they are integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
b=ka \implies 3b^3-b^2+5b=b(3b^2-b+5)=a\cdot \left( 3kb^2-kb^2+5k\right).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct, but could be simplified a lot. You have $b = ax$; we want to show that $3b^3-b^2+5b = ay$ for some $y \in \Bbb Z$.

Pulling out a factor of $b$, we have:
$$\begin{align}
3b^3-b^2+5b &= b(3b^2-b+5)\\
&= ax(3b^2-b+5)\\
&= a(3b^2x-bx+5x)
\end{align}$$
so we have explicitly constructed the necessary $y$.